# Number of subgroups of order 2017 in S2017

Tags: group-theory

I want to prove that the number of subgroups of order 2017 in the Symmetric group $S_{2017}$ equals $2015!$

First of all, 2017 is a prime number. I used that to prove that the number of elements of order 2017 in $S_{2017}$ equals $2016!$ earlier.

I tried using the Sylow Theorems to calculate this number of subgroups. I would write the order of $S_{2017}$ as $|S_{2017}| = 2017! = 2016! \cdot 2017$. Then the amount of 2017-Sylow subgroups (name this T) should divide $2016!$ and $T ≡ 1 \mod 2017.$ There are a lot of possibilties for T using just that information. I'm also not even sure that $2017$ does not divide $2016!$, but I should be able to prove that if the sylow theorems are actually useful in this question.

So I failed to find a way to find the asked number of subgroups, and anything that could help me find the answer to the question would really be appreciated.

Comment: A group of order $p$ (where $p$ is prime) contains exactly $p-1$ elements of order $p$.

Comment: So I know there are $2016!$ elements of order $2017$ in $S_{2017}$. A subgroup of order $2017$ must have $2016$ elements of order $2017$. So if all the subgroups of order 2017 were disjunct, there would be $2016! / 2016 = 2015!$ different subgroups. So do I need to prove these subgroups would be disjunct...?

Comment: They are not disjoint, every subgroup contains the identity. What you need is that two subgroups of order $p$ are either identical or have trivial intersection.

Comment: Yes, that worked, now it all makes sense :) thank you.